# Cannot build libffi custom buildpack in Heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku, libffi

Have researched this and came across [Problems with custom LIBFFI Heroku buildpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415725/problems-with-custom-libffi-heroku-buildpack), where they suggest a forked libffi buildpack.

But even after following the directions there, can't seem to get it to compile properly.  It fails with a number of `No package 'libffi' found` messages (full log below).

How can I get libffi compiled properly for a Heroku Python application?

requirements.txt file:

```
Flask==0.10.1
gunicorn==18.0
cryptography==0.3
```

Buildpack environment variable:

```
BUILDPACK_URL:                 git://github.com/mfenniak/heroku-buildpack-python-libffi.git
```

git push errors:

https://gist.github.com/HanSooloo/8a9290c032ed603f6cf4#file-libffi-errors

## UPDATE

Feeling very silly as I have clearly done a bad Copy/Paste in setting the BUILDPACK_URL environment variable in Heroku.

The forked buildpack at h++ps://github.com/kennethjiang/heroku-buildpack-python-libffi has the same `Readme.md` file as the original one at h++ps://github.com/mfenniak/heroku-buildpack-python-libffi.

Which means, if I simply copy/paste the instructions from 'kennethjiang's repo, I will actually be pointing to 'mfenniak's original repo:

kennethjiang's Readme.md:

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/mfenniak/heroku-buildpack-python-libffi.git
```

Should have done:

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/kennethjiang/heroku-buildpack-python-libffi.git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeling very silly as I have clearly done a bad Copy/Paste in setting the BUILDPACK_URL environment variable in Heroku.

The forked buildpack at https://github.com/kennethjiang/heroku-buildpack-python-libffi has the same `Readme.md` file as the original one at https://github.com/mfenniak/heroku-buildpack-python-libffi.

Which means, if I simply copy/paste the instructions from 'kennethjiang's repo, I will actually be pointing to 'mfenniak's original repo:

kennethjiang's Readme.md:

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/mfenniak/heroku-buildpack-python-libffi.git
```

Should have done:

```
$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/kennethjiang/heroku-buildpack-python-libffi.git
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently changing the BUILDPACK_URL is no longer needed.

Just add either cffi or cryptography in requirements.txt and libffi will be bootstrapped automatically.